# Bash Script SSH into MYSQL Server and create database with dash in it

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh

I keep having trouble with this command:

```
ssh -t $SSSSHUSER@$SSSSH "echo \"CREATE DATABASE \`$NEWDB\`; GRANT ALL ON \`$NEWDB\`.* TO '$SSMYSQLUSER'@'$SSMYSQLSERVER';\" | /usr/bin/mysql -u$SSMYSQLUSER -p$SSMYSQLPWD ;"
```

Even tho I escaped the backticks the database creation fails when a `-` is present in the database name. Any ideas how to fix the syntax?

When running this locally everything works:

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE \`$NEWDB\`; GRANT ALL ON \`$NEWDB\`.* TO '$MYSQLUSER'@'localhost';" | /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u"$MYSQLUSER" -p"$MYSQLPWD"
```

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to escape the backticks *again*. The shell is likely stripping the first set of escapes when it unquotes the double quoted string. That or use single quotes on the outside. Add `set -x` to the remote command string and you should see what command is actually being run.

Comment: Thanks I took your advice and this helped:
    ssh -t $SSSSHUSER@$SSSSH "echo 'CREATE DATABASE \`$NEWDB\`; GRANT ALL ON \`$NEWDB\`.* TO $SSMYSQLUSER@$SSMYSQLSERVER;' | /usr/bin/mysql -u$SSMYSQLUSER -p$SSMYSQLPWD ; "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked after debugging with set -x:

```
ssh -t $SSSSHUSER@$SSSSH "echo 'CREATE DATABASE \`$NEWDB\`; GRANT ALL ON \`$NEWDB\`.* TO $SSMYSQLUSER@$SSMYSQLSERVER;' | /usr/bin/mysql -u$SSMYSQLUSER -p$SSMYSQLPWD ; "
```